# SelectedIndex is a null reference exception?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, silverlight-4.0, nullreferenceexception

I keep getting this error:

```
System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code
  Message=[Arg_NullReferenceException]
Arguments: 
Debugging resource strings are unavailable. Often the key and arguments provide sufficient information to diagnose the problem. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=106663&Version=5.0.60401.00&File=mscorlib.dll&Key=Arg_NullReferenceException
  StackTrace:
       at Jantire.DoHomeworkView.TextAlignment_combobox_SelectionChanged(Object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.OnSelectionChanged(SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.InvokeSelectionChanged(List`1 unselectedItems, List`1 selectedItems)
       at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.SelectionChanger.End()
       at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.OnItemsChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl.OnItemCollectionChanged(Object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
       at System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection.NotifyCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection.NotifyCollectionReady()
       at System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl.NotifyAllItemsAdded(IntPtr nativeItemsControl)
  InnerException:
```

at the code:

```
private void TextAlignment_combobox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            //This next line is where error is at
            if (TextAlignment_combobox.SelectedIndex == 0)
            {
                EssayContents_richtextbox.Selection.ApplyPropertyValue(Paragraph.TextAlignmentProperty,  TextAlignment.Left);
            }
            if (TextAlignment_combobox.SelectedIndex == 1)
            {
                EssayContents_richtextbox.Selection.ApplyPropertyValue(Paragraph.TextAlignmentProperty, TextAlignment.Center);
            }
            if (TextAlignment_combobox.SelectedIndex == 2)
            {
                EssayContents_richtextbox.Selection.ApplyPropertyValue(Paragraph.TextAlignmentProperty, TextAlignment.Right);
            }
        }
```

With the XAML:

```
<ComboBox Width="128" x:Name="TextAlignment_combobox" SelectionChanged="TextAlignment_combobox_SelectionChanged" ToolTipService.ToolTip="Text Alignment">
                <ComboBoxItem Name="LeftAlignment_comboboxitem" Content="Left Alignment" IsSelected="True"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Name="CenterAlignment_comboboxitem" Content="Center Alignment"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Name="RightAlignment_comboboxitem" Content="Right Alignment"/>
            </ComboBox>
```

Comment: Provide more detail if you want an answer. i.e. what line of TextAlignment_combobox_SelectionChanged does the NullReferenceException occur?  The easier you make it to answer the question, the more answers you'll get.

Comment: I showed what line it errors out at in the code with a comment before the line. The contents of EssayContents_richtextbox are null, but how would I set a default text alignment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, I have tested this scenario out and I have found your issue.  When you initially fire the WPF application, it runs through the SelectionChanged event.  This happens as soon as the ComboBox object is created.  The problem is that on your WPF application, you have your ComboBox in the XAML before your RichTextBox.  That means that this event fires before the RichTextBox is created.  Thus, you get a Null reference exception.  You have two options.  You could eat the error or try to determine if the RichTextBox exists before you attempt to operate on it or you could move the RichTextBox up in the XAML to be above your ComboBox.  This has nothing to do with form placement but instead with placement within the XAML.  Either one will solve your issue.

Comment: That solved it! I put it before the StackPanel containing the toolbar, but it still didn't work, I'm guessing because the RichTextBox takes longer to load than a button, so I just included if (EssayContents_richtextbox != null) before each toolbar button

Answer (score 0):

Without more detail, it sounds like EssayContents_richtextbox is null.

Comment: That seems to be the issue, but how would I set a default text alignment?

Answer (score 0):

Either:

- `TextAlignment_combobox` is null (seems very unlikely)
- `EssayContents_richtextbox` is null
- or `EssayContents_richtextbox.Selection` is null

You should debug this and check them all until you find something thats null, or failing that protect against them being null in your code somehow, for example:

```
private void TextAlignment_combobox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (EssayContents_richtextbox == null || EssayContents_richtextbox.Selection == null)
    {
        // Handle me, or just
        return;
    }

    if (TextAlignment_combobox.SelectedIndex == 0)
    {
        EssayContents_richtextbox.Selection.ApplyPropertyValue(Paragraph.TextAlignmentProperty,  TextAlignment.Left);
    }
    if (TextAlignment_combobox.SelectedIndex == 1)
    {
        EssayContents_richtextbox.Selection.ApplyPropertyValue(Paragraph.TextAlignmentProperty, TextAlignment.Center);
    }
    if (TextAlignment_combobox.SelectedIndex == 2)
    {
        EssayContents_richtextbox.Selection.ApplyPropertyValue(Paragraph.TextAlignmentProperty, TextAlignment.Right);
    }
}
```

I'd guess that if `EssayContents_richtextbox` is null this is an error in your code - also looking at the documentation for the `Selection` property it seems that this will probably have a value even if there is no selection (although it doesn't explicitly say that it will never return null)

Comment: TextAlignment_combobox can't be null, or it couldn't have generated the SelectionChanged Event.  And if EssayContents_richtextbox isn't null, then Selection can't be null or else you'd never be able to set a selection on a RichTextBox

Comment: @Peter Thats not true - it is **very** unlikely given the stack trace and xaml posted (which is why I said "seems very unlikely"), but its definitely not impossible (it could have been another control that triggered the change event - I'm pretty sure I could engineer a contrived scenario where this happens).